# Account lockout caused by different PCs

Tags: windows

In a windows 2012 domain environment, an account was lockout due to incorrect password attempts. I have recently changed the password, but different security event logs in DC show that different caller computer names caused the lock, making me hard to troubleshoot the cause. I have checked for the followings in these caller PCs:

- Manually mapped network drives
- Cached passwords (Credentials Manager in Windows 7, Manage passwords
  in Windows XP)
- Any disconnected Remote Desktop sessions on possible servers

But no irregularity was found. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should also check to see if the user has any scheduled tasks or services installed and running under their (old) credentials on those PCs that are locking them out. If any are found, I would look into setting up a service account for those processes.

Comment: I have also checked any scheduled tasks or services installed and running under their (old) credentials. But no irregularity was found. Thanks